# Adding two arrays into one by using methods C#

Tags: c#

So I have an issue with methods I need to use a method to add two integers into one but by creating a second method, it doesn't understand that there are arrays when I assign method in the first method //static void main. Is there any way how to solve this issue? And is there a way to choose a method by using switch statement so that second method doesn't initialize instantly?

```
        //array1
        Random rand = new Random();
        double[] array1 = new double[9];
        Console.WriteLine("Pirma araja vertiba");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = Convert.ToDouble(rand.Next(0, 9));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        foreach (double n in array1)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", n);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        //Arrray2
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        double[] array2 = new double[9];
        Console.WriteLine("Otra araja vertiba");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            array2[i] = Convert.ToDouble(rand2.Next(0, 9));
        }
        foreach (double n in array2)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", n);
        }
        public static void Summet(Array arr1,Array  arr2) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        double[] arr3 = new double[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            arr3[i] = arr1[1] + arr2[i];
        //error here
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If you want to add integers why is everything doubles? Do you really want to add things only to the 2nd element of `arr1` Why do you think a switch statement would help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array3 = array1.Zip( array2, ( a, b ) => a + b )
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this page on how to ask a good question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I expect your error is that you are using `Array` in your method signature and that is very primitive. You need to tell the compiler what it is dealing with more explicitly

```
 public static void Summet(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
  
    double[] arr3 = new double[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        arr3[i] = arr1[1] + arr2[i];      
    }
}
```

Also I expect that `arr1[1]` is meant to be `arr[i]` but I have not corrected that in the sample above.